# send interrupt to window in screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen, gnu

How can I send a interrupt to a window within screen.  I have screen running with several windows.  Each of the windows have processes running within them.  I wish to be able to send and interrupt to a specific window ie ctrl+c.  I wish to do this without killing the window itself.  My other options is to look up the process ID and do kill -INT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with `kill -INT`, but this should work as well:

```
screen -S sessionid -X stuff $'\cc'
```